# Evolve wordpress theme, sizing the header

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am using a premium wordpress theme for a quick website I'm making. Almost everything can be set in the admin panel, which is great, but the header size is not one of them and I find it to be a bit large now. I'd like to use the 'custom css' section in the admin panel because I'm not interested in creating a whole child theme for just that one line of code.

I tried searching for the right class, something is making this thing so big, but what?

This is the url to the page I'm talking about;
http://lindenmobileappstore.nl/drsachs/

This is all the css regarding the header (that I could find at least);

```
/* 3.2. Header and subheader
==================================== */
#dp-head-wrap {background:transparent; position:relative;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    z-index:400;
    }
.page-template-template-contact-php #dp-head-wrap.semi-transparent  {

    background-color: rgba(33, 51, 68, 0.9)!important;}
#dp-head {
    position: relative;padding: 0 10px;
}

#dp-head:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#dp-head h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#dp-head a.cssLogo {
    background: transparent url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    width: 143px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 30px 15px 10px 0;
    background-size:cover;
}

#dp-head a.textLogo {
    color: #5F8CB4;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 7px 0 0 10px;
}

#dp-head a.textLogo small {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
}

#dp-head a.imageLogo {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    height:42px;
    margin: 30px 15px 10px 0;
}

#dp-head a.imageLogo img {
display: block;
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
height : 100%\9; /*hack: fixes ie8 logo*/
}





.dp-header-wrapper {
    background-color: #232D37;

    padding: 0;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
}

#dp-header {padding: 20px 0}

#dp-header .box {margin-bottom:0}

#dp-button-area {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#dp-button-area a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 42px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
color: #2d3e52;
}


#dp-header-search, #dp-logout, #dp-login  {
    color: #2d3e52;
    font-size:18px;
    display:block;
    line-height:18px;
}
#dp-header-search:hover, #dp-login:hover, #dp-logout:hover  {color:#5F8CB4;}    

#dp-header-search-form {width:100%; 
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
display:none;
background:#ffffff;
z-index:1000;}
#dp-header-search-form .dp-page {padding:50px 10px 0 10px}

#dp-header-search-form #s {
    width:95%;  
    border:none;line-height:36pxpx; 
    font-size: 36px;
    height:50px!important;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #b9bec3;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    float:left;
    padding:7px 0;
    background:transparent;
    }
#cancel-search {float:right; width:40px; height:40px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;color:#b9bec3 }
#cancel-search i {font-size:40px; text-align: center;line-height:40px;}
#cancel-search:hover {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.dp-subheader-wraper {
    background: #213344;
    padding: 0;
}
.dp-subheader {position:relative; height:120px;}
.dp-subheader .main-title {margin:0; padding:25px 0 0 10px; font-size:36px;font-weight:100;line-height:40px}
.dp-subheader .sub-title {margin:0; padding:0 0 0 10px; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; opacity:0.7;}
.dp-subheader .dp-breadcrumbs {position:absolute;right:15px;top:45px;font-size:13px;}
.dp-subheader .dp-breadcrumbs a, .dp-subheader .dp-breadcrumbs span {opacity:0.7}
.dp-subheader .dp-breadcrumbs a:hover {opacity:1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sf-menu li {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Remove menu item height and overall height will be based on logo image.